# namespacing models - FatalErrorException Call to a member function - Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm pretty sure my `FatalErrorException
Call to a member function` error is related to a namespacing error but not sure why. The models appear to load ok, it's only when I call a model method. I'll explain:

I am trying to use the method sayhi() in the modelMy directory structure is like this:

=Directory Structure=

App/Controllers

```
|-controllers
  |-api
    |-data
      |- AttendanceController.php
    |- ChartsController.php
    |- DataServeController.php
  |- ApiController.php
|- BaseController.php
```

App/Models

```
 |-models
  |-api
    |- UkAudience.php :: sayhi()
  |- BaseModel.php
  |- DataServeController.php
  |- ApiController.php
```

= Routing =

I hit the route like this:

```
Route::get('someroute',array('as' => 'get-api-data', 'uses' => 'api\DataServeController@getIndex');
```

And `DataServeController` extends from 'ApiController'

= Controllers =

Here are relevant excerpts from the respective controllers:

I am injecting interface dependencies and the models are instantiated in 'ApiController()' constructor like this. You can see how ApiController() is injecting interfaces/instantiating models.

```
// controllers/api/DataServeController.php

namespace Api;
use ApiController;

class DataServeController extends ApiController {

    public somefunction(){
        echo $this->UkAudience->sayhi();
    }
}

// controllers/ApiController.php

class ApiController extends BaseController {

/**
 * UKAudience Model
 * @var UKAudience
 */
protected $UKAudience;

public function __construct(Api\UKAudience $UKAudience){
     parent::__construct();
 $this->Broadcast = $Broadcast;
}

...
```

= Model ==

So the model appears to load without Laravel complaining.. But when I try to use the function I get `Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to a member function sayhi() on a non-object`

```
  // models/api/UKAudience.php  
  namespace Api;
use DataServe;

class UkAudience extends DataServe {


    public function sayhi(){
        return 'hello!!';
    }
}
```

Any pointers / tips / help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where do you assign `$UKaudience` to a pointer in your constructor?  Don't forget this part:

```
public function __construct(Api\UKAudience $UKAudience){
     parent::__construct();
 $this->Broadcast = $Broadcast;
 $this->UKAudience = $UKAudience;  // This is required if you want to use objects in this class.
}
```

You should then be able to call this function using:
`$this->UKAudience->sayhi()`